# What are classes named somethingEntity?

Tags: java, class, entity, naming-conventions, apache-httpcomponents

I see that in Java there are some implementations named somethingEntity (`HttpEntity`, `FileEntity`,`InputStreamEntity`, `StringEntity`,...) - found them [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentLength())

1. Why do we have them (reason, usage)?
2. What is this "Entity" at the end? because it seems it is different from [Java Entities](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html)

Comment: Just a descriptive noun that was in favor when the Apache Commons HTTP library authors were naming classes.  The Java EE spec clearly uses "Entity" to mean "persistent EJB in a relational database", but that goes back to 1990s and EJB 1.0 spec.

Comment: thanks! I thought it was something special behind this second part of the name. So just as Stream is for InputStream. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes are named with the suffix `Entity` because they are implementations of the [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) class. Otherwise, they might be confused with [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html), [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) etc. classes which are included in Java SE. This is an example of the naming convention.

Summary: A naming convention and to distinguish from Java SE classes.